# Sub query result using golang from salesforce

Tags: query, go

I am using a library similar to simpleforce: https://github.com/simpleforce/simpleforce to retrieve query result from Salesforce in golang.

The retrieved result will be in SObject type which basically works as a map in golang. Generally it works fine so if I want to retrieve say status field it is just like record["status"]

But when it comes to complicated query like `Select Id, (Select Id From Cases) From Account`.

Then record["Cases"] would ideally be a list. But in this case I would think it will be a json string in the output SObject record in golang.

I am wondering how may I retrieve the id of the cases in this scenario? Should I unmarshal the json string and then fetch it?

Answer (score 0):

When you are inside the salesforce it does provide the data in list format. This could be a reason since you are outside the salesforce so below are the different ways you can retrieve the cases.

1. you can parse the json and create a list.
2. retrieve the accounts first and create a list of account id(for eg :-

// not sure the since about the syntax of Golang so writing it in apex

```
List<String> accountId = new list<String>(); 
for(account acc:accountsRetrieved){   
   accountId.add(acc.Id); 
}
```

Now you can again hit the salesforce and query the case using below soql Query

**select id,name from case where accoundid in :accountId**